# How can I inject a different service in an existing one, i.e. exchange one already injected service by an own one?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection, symfony-services

The basic authentication provider service uses the user.auth service:

```
basic_auth.authentication.basic_auth:
    class: Drupal\basic_auth\Authentication\Provider\BasicAuth
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@user.auth', '@flood', '@entity.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: authentication_provider, provider_id: 'basic_auth', priority: 100 }
```

I wrote an own service my-user.auth (extending UserAuthInterface) and want my service to be injected into the basic authentication provider instead of the user.auth. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that you only want to change what is injected to basic auth authentication? What about all the other cases like a normal login? Might make more sense in your case to just alter the user.auth service and replace it with your own implementation?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I want to alter the user.auth service, therefore I wrote an own one, and now I am trying to replace it everywhere it is used. Is there a way to alter it directly?

Comment: Sure, in exactly the same way as the answer here, just alter that service and call setClass(), possibly with different arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I think this makes much more sense in my case. Is there any priority handling? What happens if multiple modules alter the same service?

Comment: Service builders are called based on the module weight I think. Obviously, a change like setClass() can only be done by one module and the one called last will win. There is a concept called service decorator, which allows you to define a service that is wrapping the original service. Then in theory multiple decorators can be combined, but this only makes sense if you only want to do something *additional* to the default behavior, if you do not call the inner service then you are still having a conflict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a ServiceProvider in your module. And then replace the argument using `Definition::replaceArguments` like so:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

// @note: You only need Reference, if you want to change service arguments.
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

/**
 * Modifies the language manager service.
 */
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('basic_auth.authentication.basic_auth');
    $definition->replaceArgument(1, 'NEW_SERVICE');
  }
}
```

Please note:

> Note that if you want this service alteration to be recognized
>   automatically, the name of this class is required to be a CamelCase
>   version of your module's machine name followed by ServiceProvider, it
>   is required to be in your module's top-level namespace
>   Drupal\your_module_name, and it must implement
>   \Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceModifierInterface (which
>   ServiceProviderBase does).

Relevant article: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services